# content being replaced on hover, but existing text not being removed

Tags: jquery

Sorry if this question is explained a bit poorly JQuery is not my "native" language, so I'll try to explain as best I can.  (and I've set up a jsfiddle to help show the code) http://jsfiddle.net/6eYYR/

I have a webpage here: http://www.waranuwater.com.au/pages/test-1 I had a colleague assist me, in getting to the point I am now with the Jquery.

Scroll down to the second area, I have two divs set up side-by-side, one on the left contains an imagemap, the other on the right a "content area" with html content. The "content area" contains some text that will change when the user hovers over a part of the imagemap.

I've managed to get the content (which I have made black to make it easier to see for the timebeing) to change when the relevant part of the imagemap is hovered ,  when the user hovers over the imagemap, but I can't work out how to have the initial content disappear when the hover occurs (the bit that starts with "Complete Contaminant Removal")

This is my current Jquery code:

```
 function showHideDivs(indx){
            hideDivs();
            oShowHideDivs[indx].style.display = 'block';
        }
        function hideDivs(){
            for(i=0; i < oShowHideDivs.length; i++){
                oShowHideDivs[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        window.onload=function(){
            oShowHideDivs =  
document.getElementById('ccontainer').getElementsByTagName('div');
            var oMap = document.getElementById('myMap');
            for(i=0; i < oMap.areas.length; i++){
                oMap.areas[i].indx = i;
                oMap.areas[i].onmouseover=function(){showHideDivs(this.indx);}
                oMap.areas[i].onmouseout = hideDivs;
            }
        }
```

Am I missing something here?  Do I need to tell Jquery to "hide" the existing text?, and if so how would I go about doing that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "initial content" is not inside any `div`, so it will be unaffected by your show/hide div logic. I'd suggest first placing it in its own div, just like the others:

```
<div id="ccontainer">
    <div id="Sediment-Filter">...</div>
    <div id="Anti-Bacterial-Filter">...</div>
    <div id="Proteus-RO-Membrane">...</div>
    <div id="Activated-Coconut-Carbon">...</div>
    <div id="Initial-Contents">
        <h3>Complete Contaminant Removal</h3>
        <p>What truly sets this system apart ...
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Now it will be hidden just like the others when `hideDivs` is called. Your next step is show it by default when the other divs are hidden:

```
    function hideDivs(showInitial){
        for(i=0; i < oShowHideDivs.length; i++){
            oShowHideDivs[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        if ( showInitial )
            document.getElementById('Initial-Contents').style.display = 'block';
    }
```

...unless you're showing a specific div:

```
function showHideDivs(indx){
    hideDivs(false); // Don't show initial contents
    oShowHideDivs[indx].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Note that `showInitial` is "truthy" when it's an `Event` object, so you can still use it directly in the `oMap.areas[i].onmouseout = hideDivs;` line.

(BTW your question does not use jQuery, just vanilla JavaScript - though there is jQuery elsewhere in your page)

Comment: thanks for the reply @mgibsonbr, is the hidedivs function you provided replacing the existing hidedivs function that I had? 

From my understanding what's happening is that all divs within "ccontainer" are getting there visability set to "none" and then a mouseover triggers "display: block;" 

Is my logic correct?

Comment: @JustinBrown yes, however when none of the areas are being hovered, you still want one div to show up (the initial contents). So I suggested adding an optional parameter `initialAlso` that, if `true`, also keeps the initial contents hidden, otherwise shows it (the last `if`). When the function is called normally (for ex. in the `oMap.areas[i].onmouseout = hideDivs`) it hides every div **except** for the initial one; when the function is called with a `true` parameter (inside `showHideDivs`) it hides every div **including** the initial one - and then the specific one is shown. Clear now?

Comment: yeah it's getting clearer, I have tried implementing the solution, and I am still get the "initial contents" appearing, I'm wondering if I got a "curly brace" in the wrong place? I've adjusted the jsfiddle js code, so you can see what I've got.

Comment: @JustinBrown you forgot to pass `true` to `hideDivs` when called from `showHideDivs`, that's why it's appearing also. But scrap that, I forgot that when you assign it to `onmouseout` it's called with an `Event` argument (i.e. it's "truthy"), so it's better to invert the logic (instead of a `!initialAlso` use a `showInitial`). Check my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for that, I think it was a case of me "seeing what I expected to see" rather than "what was actually there" :)

Answer (score 1):

I can see jquery reference in your code, why not use jquery?
Below is the solution

Provide classname to those elements which you need to hide something like

```
<h3 class="tohide">Complete Contaminant Removal</h3>
<p class="tohide">.......
.....
```

Updated method:

```
function showHideDivs(indx){
            hideDivs();
            oShowHideDivs[indx].style.display = 'block';
            $(".tohide").hide();
        }
```

You may need to show original elements when you hide all divs,

```
function hideDivs(){
            for(i=0; i < oShowHideDivs.length; i++){
                oShowHideDivs[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
            $(".tohide").show();
        }
```

Use jquery for all such task, it will reduce development time, efforts and code.

If you still want to use native javascript, then you will need to wrap all the elements which you need to hide in `<span id="tohide">` and show hide this element based on hover selection.